# Flash driver for 220V lamps according to the state of two switches

Tags: components, schematics, circuit-design

I am an absolute beginner in electronics.
I would like to actualize the simplest circuit capable to pilot small 220V lamps (in parallel), making them flashing according to the state of two switches and according to the following rules:

- if both switch A and switch B are off, the lamps are off;
- if switch A is on, the lamps are on;
- if switch B is on, the lamps flash at about 1 Hz or little more, regardless to previous rules.

Lamps don't need more than 150 W in total.

It would be appreciated to have some explanation on how to vary the on/off cycle of flashing, remaining in the range about 1 Hz - 5 Hz.

Maybe what I need is a simple modification of this circuit, that satisfy switch B rule, but need to implement switch A functionality (to be always on, without flashing, ONLY IF A is off):

[image]

Many thanks!!

Comment: do we assume Tungsten filaments with up to 10x surge current?

Comment: Yes, we could; however, I use something like this, to give you some idea; but I can change the light bulb accordingly your specifications...: https://www.domuswire.com/search/scheda_prodotto.jsp?cprodotto=gewiss%20GW20607&t=Segnalazione+-+SYSTEM+WHITE&ccategoria=794

Comment: Are switches AB logic or line voltage and are they SPST or SPDT

Comment: They are physical relais (or manual switches for light bulbs). (Sorry but I dont' know what "SPST" and  "SPDT" mean...)

Comment: SPST =1P1T , SPDT=1P2T contacts. This makes a big difference in implementation ... also translate "
Tenuta 
del frutto al supporto: > 0,6J" in lamp spec

Comment: flashing is easy after you better define the interfaces for V,I Z ( for surge impedance)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, providing yet another unexplained abbreviation when asked what something means is usually not helpful.

Comment: @RobertoTognelli, ([Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=SPST)) SPST = Single Pull Single Throw. It means 1 circuit (pull) is being switched and it is either closed or open (on/off) to one destination (throw). SPDT = Single Pull Double Throw means 1 circuit is is switched to one of two destinations (i.e. the single circuit is closed to either destination). Such switches may also have (see spec sheet) a third position where neither destination is connected.

Comment: if he does not know any switch types, there may be more questions on the Lamp specs he needs to ask.

Comment: For the one who is an *absolute beginner in electronics*, one should note the above circuit is dangerous as it charges the capacitor up >>300V with an energy of about 10 Joule, and no means to discharge it when unplugged from the mains. That charge sits there until someone touches.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to buy an Arduino relay board and then control it from outside (eg : sending a 1Hz on/off pulse).

[image]

Some of those boards can handle up to 10A. This should be far enough for what you want (10A x 220V = 2200W). Make sure you buy one with optocouplers (as on the picture above) for safety.

Sending the on/off pulse and implementing the logic you want can be done using an Arduino (or any other microcontroller) or a simpler circuit like a 555 timer in astable mode (and some AND/OR gates).

I would avoid trying to implement yourself the part that deals with 220V (eg : using a triac + transistor, as found on some schematics on the web) as it can be dangerous.

Comment: note, however, that mechanical relais are only rated for a finite amount of switching cycles (but that number can pretty high!). Note that endurance of the switches is pretty much a function of their price – but even relatively cheap ones, for example [these](http://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Omron-Electronics/G5LE-1-ASI-DC3/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtGt%252bn33CgIP2ptscmC2PsxOrWAX4XVfsU%3d) would withstand >36,000 switchings under load. I'd actually recommend making sure you get your relay board from a reputable source with relays to which you get a datasheet that specifies endurance – (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) there's a lot of ultra-cheap relays on the market, and a lot of counterfeits. So, especially with hardware coming directly from China, where you wouldn't have any laws guaranteeing you can return wrong/faulty products, be very cautious. Send an email and ask for confirmation on the relay brand, and model.

Comment: would triacs be a better option ?

Comment: technically, to switch a purely resistive load, yes, triacs would be good– especially you effectively don't care that much and let them just turn of with the next voltage zero crossing after turning off the control voltage. **I completely agree with you**, however: **don't electrocute yourself** just because you want to build something yourself.A mains voltage application must be properly isolated from the control electronics and the human operating the device(optocouplers, typically), and a triac device will need some reliable snubber circuitry if it's not supposed to turn into a fire hazard!

Comment: (snubbing really is only necessary if your load isn't as a perfect resistor as your actual tungsten wire – for example, if someone mistakenly screws in an LED or cold fluorescence lamp with a switch mode power supply, you still want your triac to turn off; Triac circuitry isn't that complicated, but handling mains voltage is still not the first electronic project one should do)

Comment: Agreed .. there is a huge variation in contact material quality that can accelerate aging in the presence of a reactive load and high toggle rates with high contact temperatures. Due diligence and experience is necessary.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, For the part you linked: The 36,000 cycles is woefully inadequate if this is going to be operating at 1Hz (at max load). That would be only 10hr of continuous operation. 1Hz also exceeds the 1,800op/hr spec on electrical (no info at lower loads). The graphs for life expectancy indicate you might get into the 11-12 day continuous 1Hz operation (1M cycles) at the much lower load (150W) indicated in the Question. Note also that using a mechanical relay may result in acoustic noise audible to users when switched. Such could end up being quite annoying to the users.

Comment: @Makyen I agree, it's only 10hrs of continuous full-load operation; again, this is the cheapest relais I could find on mouser, and the point was **to illustrate that knowing one's use case is crucial to selecting the right component**. For example, if the circuit used is just blinking a "nuclear meltdown" lamp for at most 10min (before the lamp itself fails due to the nuclear meltdown), this might be totally appropriate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I did not get that was what you were attempting to illustrate from your prior comment. I definitely agree, use case is, usually, critical.  I like your example :-).

Comment: MTBF needs to be defined for use

Comment: @MarcusMüller there are also Arduino-compatible SSR boards with similar separation of mains and LV, and similarly with screw terminals

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to plunk down $40 on a time delay relay capable of repeat cycle (flasher) operation, here's probably the simplest way to do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f63eJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SWA is a standard single pole switch, SWB is a changeover (2-way/3-way) switch, and U1 is a [Macromatic TE-8816U time delay relay](http://www.alliedelec.com/macromatic-te-8816u/70819839/) set to function B (repeat cycle, starts in OFF) and the flash rate you wish.

The TE-8816U was chosen as it's reasonably priced, can accept 220/240VAC input, is UL listed (vs just being UL component recognized), and has a reasonably long-lived set of contacts (70,000 operations electrical at rated load).

Comment: good assuming B is 1P2T contact

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 -- yeah -- why I said it was a changeover (i.e. 2-way/3-way) switch :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is ;

- if B =1 , output Y=1 flashing 0.5 Hz square wave = F
- if B =0 or B!=1. and A= 1 , Y=1
- otherwise Y=0, let ! = invert, *=AND, +=OR

  - so C= A*B!
  - then Y = C + B*F

However since you are driving a 220Vac LED load with a Switched reactive regulator, it is important to get the preferred switching method from supplier such as a zero crossing Triac or 10A AC relay rated for reactive input impedance, since specs indicate poor Power Factor = 0.6?.

We also need to know exact Specs of A,B input signals and expected MTBF of unit to factor surge currents , switch ratings etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpvweJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BOM Cost $5 est. For 1 Schmitt NAND, ,1 opto ZCS triac, and  1uF Caps .  For wetting the contacts with low current logic, it is critical to choose C1 depending on contact rating and plating. The  RC value also debounces the switch and the cap attenuates ESD, critical for long cables.

Comment: Any improvements? comments?

Comment: I guess the Op is trying to avoid answering perhaps due to language difficulty.